# Selected option no longer updates Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am writing an app for an assignment and ran into the issue where i need the value of a selection made by the user, but i keep getting the one that was selected as a default;

I'm using this select:

```
<select v-model="selectedType" @change="onTypeChange($event)">
        <option v-for="type in types" :key="type" :selected="selectedType = cabin.type">
          {{type}}
        </option>
      </select>
```

And this is part of my data:

```
export default {
  name: 'CabinsDetail32',
  props: ['cabin'],
  data () {
    return {
      types: [
        'GEAR',
        'SMALLDT',
        'SMALL',
        'LARGE',
        'FAMILY'],
      selectedType: this.type
}
```

I have tried rewriting the select to not use a v-model and tried using a different way of setting the default selected, but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **selected** attribute of the **option** tag. The **selected** attribute **specifies that an option should be pre-selected when the page loads**

This links may help:

1. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#select
2. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

To update the prop from the child try **.sync** modifier:

Parent component:

```
<ParentComponent 
 :cabin="cabin" 
 :selectedCabinType.sync="selectedType" // selectedType will update every time child component selects type
</ParentComponent>

<script>
 data() {
  return {
   // ... your data
   selectedType: '', // or provide the default type
  }
 },
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<select v-model="selectedType" @change="onTypeChange($event)">
  <option v-for="type in types" :key="type :selected="selectedType = cabin.type">
    {{type}}
  </option>
</select>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CabinsDetail32',
  props: ['cabin', 'selectedCabinType'],
  data () {
    return {
      types: [
        'GEAR',
        'SMALLDT',
        'SMALL',
        'LARGE',
        'FAMILY'],
      selectedType: this.type
  },
  methods: {
   onTypeChange(e) {
    this.$emit('update:selectedCabinType', e)
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but what if i want the default selected item to the one the user has clicked on?

Comment: are you getting the data which user clicked on by the props? It is not clear from the code

Comment: yes i am getting the data from the props and i want to update the value, when a different option is selected in the select

Comment: I updated the answer, try to modify your code as in the example by using .sync

Comment: more info about the .sync read here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events#sync-Modifier